# Can Travis-CI run Codeception tests?

Tags: testing, travis-ci, codeception

I'm creating my tests (though I'm a beginner, learning) using Codeception. This includes acceptance and unit tests for now.

I want to add my repo to Travis CI so I can automate testing process after each commit and put build-status tag.

I would like to ask;

1. Can Travis-CI run codeception tests?
2. Can Travis-CI run codeception acceptance tests emulating browser?
3. If both answers are no, is there any other CI tool which can?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible to run Codeception tests, including acceptance tests that run using WebDriver, on Travis CI.

It is [possible to run your tests with a real browser on Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#using-xvfb-to-run-tests-that-require-a-gui), but it is easiest to use a headless browser, since Travis is running on a headless machine. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is perfect for this, and it comes pre-installed with Travis CI's build bootstrap.

To run the tests with PhantomJS, you'll need to configure the WebDriver module like this in your `.yml` Codeception configuration file:

```
modules:
    config:
        WPWebDriver:
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'
            browser: phantomjs
```

The URL is important. I have found that attempting to use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` will not work. Also, if you accidentally leave out the `http://`, that won't work either. You can use most any `8***` port, since most of them are open, but of course you'll need to have a web server running on that port to serve your static files or run your PHP application. The easiest way to do this, I find, is to use PHP's built-in webserver.

Your `.travis.yml` file might look something like this:

```
# Travis CI configuration file.

language: php

php:
    - 5.6
    - 7.0

before_script:
    # Start up a web server.
    - php -S 127.0.0.1:8888 -t /path/to/web/root >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    # Start up the webdriver.
    - phantomjs --webdriver=4444 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    # Install Codeception.
    # Doing this last gives the webdriver and server time to start up.
    - composer install --prefer-source

script:
    - vendor/bin/codecept run
```

You will of course need to add Codeception to your project's `composer.json` file:

```
composer require --dev codeception/codeception
```

You'll also need to change `path/to/web/root` above to the path to the directory where you want the server's document root to be.

If you'd like to see a working demo running WebDriver tests against WordPress, you can check out [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/JDGrimes/wp-browser-travis-demo).

Answer (score 2):

I'd think that it can be done, but gluing everything tohether is not going to be for the faint of heart. Reason why I think it can be done is that codeception, itself, is ci-ed on Travis. See https://travis-ci.org/Codeception/Codeception. I'd contact the people at codeception and ask for their thoughts.

Or you can take a peek at how they do it in the build logs, such as:
https://travis-ci.org/Codeception/Codeception/jobs/14432638
Looks like they're running headless with a downloaded standalone selenium server.

Travis-ci have [some information on how to run GUI tests](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/). In particular, they allow you to use a [sauce labs](http://saucelabs.com) account and run distributed selenium tests from there.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today and I solved it by adding Codeception to my `composer.json`:

```
"require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "^2.1"
},
```

and referring to it on my `.travis.yml`:

```
install:
    - composer self-update
    - composer install

before_script:
    - #Code that creates and seeds my database and so on

script: php vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept run
```